# Nativescript Autosync with server use REST API

Tags: rest, asynchronous, synchronization, nativescript

Hello Nativescript user,
I have build nativescript App that get data from REST API and save to `application-settings`. Something like this :

```
fetch(config.apiUrl, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        "X-Auth-Token": sTOKEN
    }
}).then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    }, function (e) {
        console.log("Error occurred " + e);
    })
    .then(function (data) {
            appSettings.remove(sPARAMETER_DATA);
            appSettings.setString(sPARAMETER_DATA, JSON.stringify(data.sort()));
            arrayData.set('DATA', new observableArray.ObservableArray(data.sort()));
    });
```

So, if want data uptodate must GET again. 
The question : Can use this appSettings save data locally like SQLite ? And how to autosync with server use REST API JSON ?
Thanks anyway

Comment: 'application-settings' is a simple key:value store. If you want to store something more complex then you will have to use JSON.stringify to turn arrays and objects into strings (and the JSON.parse on retrieval).
Syncing with the server will have to be done via polling unless you want to setup websockets or similar

Comment: Thanks Mr. @jalal. Can you give me some examples about syncing with server use websocket in Nativescript ? Thanks anyway

Comment: I haven't used them in {N}. You could take a look here: https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-websockets